# Two iPhones plugged to Mac, can I deploy to both at the same time?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Let's say I have 2 different iPhones plugged into my Mac. Can I deploy my app to both devices at the same time?  Even when I can see both phones in Organizer, xCode only seems to recognize one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use both of them at the same time but you can choose the active device from the Active Executable section of the drop-down list on the top left of Xcode. There should be one executable for each device.

Answer (score 2):

As of xCode 3.2.5 you can have multiple devices connected to your xcode instance. You just need to select target device in Active Executable session. You can debug only on one device at a time.